# typo3 news: allowed content elements on news container $contentElements

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want to add custom content elements on the container "Inhaltselemente".

The textmedia element and several other elements works.

But if i add a custom comtent eleemnt from my own extension, or from mask export i get the following error:

"Wert ist nicht erlaubt"

the HTML CE also does'nt work.

see also screen[image]

Comment: Extensions like gridelements add the function to exclude content elements for a specific colPos. Maybe the storage folder which is holding your news records is affected by any kind of backend layout which does not allow those record types? Or maybe they are excluded by the Page-TSConfig?

Comment: i tried a lot, but i didn't find the reason for the error message.

i made a news bug issue
https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/406

Answer (score 1):

Check your rights configuration and your PageTS settings on the news folder.
Look for something like:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
     removeItems := addToList(html)
}
```

This will at least trigger the message you see above.

Comment: Can use this in T3 v7.6.21 either